# Pros and cons of centralised vs decentralised power deliver for small devices

Tags: power-supply, mains, efficiency, low-voltage

How does compare using one power supply for multiple devices vs each device having its own - regarding efficiency eg. power consumption?

**Model situation:** 
Home automation using low power devices such as sensors with Arduino, Raspberry Pi, Esp8266. Given 5-12V is not smart over long distances in a house, assume 24V power supply.

**Choice:**

- Put low voltage cabling and power devices either directly from 24V or use a voltage converter to step-down to 3, 5, 12V respectively.
- Each device will have its own small power supply from mains voltage, such as hi-link or similar.

Is there another aspects to consider aside from obvious like labour and cost of putting separate cabling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributing 5 V or 12 V **can** be smart **if** the currents are low enough (much less than 100 mA for example) so voltage drop isn't an issue. But an RPi already exceeds that.

Other things to consider:

**Reliability**, if everything is running on that 24 V and it breaks, nothing works. If you use a mains adapter for each device, the risk is more spread out. Also you might have a spare adapter available or swap an adapter until you have replaced the faulty one.

**Efficiency**, the 24 Adapter will need to power everything at full load. That might mean it is much less efficient at lower loads. Compare with PC power supplies, these can deliver a lot of power but often only reach their rated efficiency when loaded with at  least 60 % of their maximum load.

In my opinion, unless you have many low-power devices, using a 24 V distributed power is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Extendability: all devices you can buy come with a mains power supply.

Now, you buy a new *Smart Hamster*<sup>TM</sup>  and it comes with a special wireless charger that has mains on one side, and a special place for your *Smart Hamster*<sup>TM</sup> to go to recharge. Your 24 V system is useless, because you don't want to (also, can't) redesign that system to use 24 V.